# printing an object

Tags: java

What does the following System.out print in the following code??

```
class ExampleTest  {}
public class Test {
  public static void main(String ... strings){
    ExampleTest et=new ExampleTest();
    System.out.println(et);
    System.out.println(new ExampleTest());
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it?  Or is your question *why* it prints out what it prints out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you give any object to a print method, such as in your code, it will call the `toString()` method.

In your example, your `ExampleTest` class does not override this `toString()` method, so it will call the `Object.toString()`:

```
public String toString() {
return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

So the output will be the full name of the class, and the result of the `hashCode` of this class.

Here is what the [Javadoc of java.lang.Object.toString()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) says about that:

> Returns a string representation of the
>   object. In general, the toString
>   method returns a string that
>   "textually represents" this object.
>   The result should be a concise but
>   informative representation that is
>   easy for a person to read. It is
>   recommended that all subclasses
>   override this method.
>
> The toString method for class Object
>   returns a string consisting of the
>   name of the class of which the object
>   is an instance, the at-sign character
>   `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal
>   representation of the hash code of the
>   object. In other words, this method
>   returns a string equal to the value
>   of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It prints the class name followed by the `@` symbol, followed by the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the object's hashcode.

Comment: No, that is what Object does. As every other class in Java extends object, every other class will do the same UNLESS it has overriden its toString() method. For example, if you print out an Integer, you wont get the @ symbol, followed by the hash, but rather what you would expect: the number contained in the Integer. 
Better look @romaintaz' s answer.

Comment: @baba: Do you see a overidden `toString` in OP's `ExampleTest` class?